# How to pass parameter from Django template?

Tags: django, templates

1) Is it possible to catch value of ChoiceField in a template when clicking on a hyperlink? How and where to store and pass it?

2) Is there event of item changing in ChoiceField?

More simple solutions will be preferable.

EDIT: simple button with POST is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd better look at javascript for this. With jQuery, you should be able to read out the value of a select box, and append it to your hyperlink.